# Field from form:select not being set in modelAttribute on form submit using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, forms, modelattribute

Form class

```
 public class DocumentCaptureForm {
        private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DocumentCaptureForm.class);

        private String artifactCaptureJSON;
        private String isBackside;

        public String getArtifactCaptureJSON() {
            return artifactCaptureJSON;
        }

        public void setArtifactCaptureJSON(String artifactCaptureJSON) {
            this.artifactCaptureJSON = artifactCaptureJSON;
        }

        public String getIsBackside() {
            return isBackside;
        }

        public void setIsBackside(String isBackside) {
            this.isBackside = isBackside;
        }
```

JSP

```
<form:form modelAttribute="documentCaptureForm"  action="/capture" method="post" autocomplete="off">

        <div><form:hidden path="artifactCaptureJSON" id="artifactCaptureJSON"/></div>

        Document Side<form:select id="isBackside" path="isBackside">
            <form:option selected="selected" value="Front">Front</form:option>
            <form:option value="Back">Back</form:option>
        </form:select>

        <input type="submit"  id="capturesave" value="Save" />  
</form:form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/capture", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView captureArtifacts(@PathVariable long applicationPKId,
        @ModelAttribute("documentCaptureForm") DocumentCaptureForm documentCaptureForm, BindingResult result, 
        HttpServletRequest request){
    logger.debug("Entering captureArtifacts ...");

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(DOCUMENT_CAPTURE_VIEW);
    mav.addObject("title", "Capture Document");
    ArtifactCaptureData artifactData = documentCaptureForm.convertToJava();

    boolean isBackside = documentCaptureForm.getIsBackside().equals("Back");
```

artifact capture JSON has it's value set in a javascript function after the user does something on the page. That value is correctly populated when the form is posted to the controller. The field from the form select however appears to be ignored. isBackside is null no matter what I try

Answer (score 0):

In `<form:select>` tag, besides a 'path' attribute you can add 'items' attribute with passing to it a  list with several options. So you can do something like this:

```
<form:select path="isBackside" items="${['Front','Back']}" />
```

This is the simplest way to do this.